# How can I add extra groups to Finder's recognised kinds

Tags: macos, finder, tweaks

presently when I attempt to group files in Finder (Yosemite 10.10.3) by **kind** the created *Documents* category creates a vast number of files including CSVs DOCX etc:
[image]
Is it possible to make this groupings more efficient, by:

1. Grouping files by extension **-or-**
2. Defining what extensions are classified where, for instance in case of the *Documents* category I would like for it to contain only PDFs and DOC/X-XLS/X files whereas CSVs could be in a separate *data* category. The *developer* category is particularly messy as it tends to contain hundreds of files, lot of them created automatically when working with *.tex files.

Comment: I would imagine that you would need to build Spotlight plugins for the file types in order for them to show up with their own categories.

Comment: @StuartH, thanks. To be honest this is not most fortunate solution. As a matter of fact I came across [similar discussion](http://superuser.com/questions/371892/osx-assign-extension-to-content-kind), I don't believe how tedious is that. Windows 7 ability to group files by extension seems to be much more efficient.

Comment: agreed, it's a pretty time consuming ordeal. Have you looked at the possibility of an AppleScript that you could trigger to create a smart search using the current folder for scope? For example, when triggered, you could define the extension you want the script to isolate within your current folder and have it create a temporary smart search for you to use.

Comment: @StuartH I didn't consider this possibility. In my naivety, I was hoping that it would be simply a matter of typing some commands in the terminal in order to associate, let it be `*.tex` extension with `LaTeX` or `Publishing` category. Right now all the `tex` files are crammed with other stuff in the `Developer` category which renders it practically useless.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: I don't think you can change or add to the defined groups. As best I can tell groups are defined on the system level, based on Apple-declared [uniform type identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009258-SW1) (UTI). I suppose one could (conceivably) add new UTIs by creating an app that declares them and propagates them to the system, but that seems like overkill.

However, there are a couple of options you might try:

- Group by *Application*: This will group all files together by the default application that opens them. It's more fine-grained than *Kind*, but depending on how your application defaults are set up it might not produce the results you want.
- Group by *Tags*: This will involve some prep-work setting up Folder Action scripts that will tag your files according to your desired criteria, but this gives you fine-grained control over how files are grouped in Finder windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating several saved searches, each for a specific file extension within a given folder, and then add each saved search to the **Finder** sidebar. For example:

1. In **Finder**, go to your working folder, then type something (e.g., xxx) in the **Search** field.
2. This reveals the **Search** row; click the '**+**' at the far right.
3. Change **Kind** to **File extension**, and type one of the extensions you need.
4. Remove the "xxx" or whatever you had originally typed.
5. Click the **Save** button.
6. Type a meaningful name for your search (e.g., **Documents - PDF**), and tick the **Add To Sidebar** checkbox.

Now that you have a saved search in the Finder sidebar, you can make duplicates of it.

7. In the **Finder**, right-click the **Documents - PDF** (that you just created), and choose **Show in Enclosing Folder**.
8. Duplicate your saved search, and rename it to something like **Documents - DOC** (i.e., for whatever you intend it to represent).
9. Select the duplicate search, and choose **File** menu >> **Add To Sidebar**.
10. In the **Finder** sidebar, click the **Documents - DOC** shortcut you just created.
11. Then right-click the shortcut and choose **Show Search Criteria**.
12. At this point, change **PDF** to **DOC**. Optionally, you could click '**+**' and add **DOCX** here, as well.

Unfortunately, you can't modify the folder location that a saved search points to; this seems like an oversight, but there you go.

Comment: What I'm interested in, I as a method to modify the categories that are applied when the Finder sorts files by *kind*. Some of them (developer and documents in particular) are too big to be useful. I want to be able to apply this sorting to any folder I'm, I don't want to have **X** saved searches available, I'll be always creating new ones for different folders.